# access another window's application's resource

Tags: windows, kernel, privileges, autoit

Even if you don't know AutoIt you may have some good insight into this question, as AutoIt is not a completely unique language. It is a language that provides an easy access into the window's dll's.

I'm trying to make a program to run with Windows Journal using the language AutoIt in order to select it's colors by hotkey. I've gotten most of the script finished and working. I'm just now making a GUI for it. I've found that it does use an `imagelist` for the images of the colors displayed. I want to use that exact image list in my GUI for a more user-friendly appearance. My problem is that I am not able to grab it and use it. I've tried copying it as well and to no avail. I think it's probably due to the fact that my application does not have the appropriate privileges to access that program's resources.

My script is this (and many variations of this):

```
$hWnd = ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:JournalApp]", "", 113) ;113 is the control ID for the color selecting toolbar 
$hImageJS = _GUICtrlToolbar_GetImageList($hWnd)   
$hImage = _GUIImageList_Duplicate($hImageJS) 
ConsoleWrite(_GUIImageList_GetImageCount($hImage)&"<--count")
```

I know that there is an image list, as I have found that I get returns that would support this idea from `GUICtrlToolbar_GetButtonImage($hWnd, $cmdId)`.

I always get 0 from the `imagecount`. I've tried various approaches, such as accessing it directly and to no avail. Any ideas / suggestions / comments?

Is there a way to have one window's program access the resources of another window's program? Is there a special permission or privilege that can be set in the kernel32 dll?

Comment: If you can't get any help from here; either set a bounty, or go the the AutoIt forum. http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/

Comment: If you re-read your comment, you'll notice it sounds more like you're giving command than a suggestion, though I'm sure you didn't mean it like that. I'm aware of what my options are. Thank you for your input. I've tried the AutoIt Forums before I posted here and recently have gotten a response which was that it was not possible. I believe anything is possible in computing and therefore I will leave this question up. Maybe someone will give me a better answer.

Comment: Your correct, If I had meant to make it a statement I would have put it in an answer form. Nonetheless, I posted it in a comment because it is your question and thought if you posted on the AutoIt forum you might get a quick response. For the impossible answer; I'd have to agree with you.

Comment: Consequently, I did find a work around which I will post later in the AutoIt forum as an answer to my question. I will not post it here, however, as it may lead others to believe that the question was answered, which it wasn't. On a side note, you're quite the editor I've noticed. Incorrect grammar bugs me too, so I'm not complaining. On a side side note, you should've used "you're" and not "your". Also "If" should have been preceded by a period. :P Cheers.

Comment: You are very correct in calling me that! It annoys me very much when people do not have almost perfect grammar and spelling, but nonetheless thank you for those pointers. Good idea on not posting it here, because you could have someone come in and give you a much better answer than you might have gotten on the AutoIt forum.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry you didn't get help on the AutoIt forum, but what you are doing is far beyond the level of hobbyist coders, who make up most of our community.

In theory you are right, everything is possible in programming.

You can't access the data because you are a different process. To do so you'd have to create a block of memory in the other program, add some code, and execute it. That process is called injection.

The process for injection is fairly simple, pretty much these function calls: `_WinAPI_OpenProcess`, `_MemVirtualAllocEx`, `_WinAPI_WriteProcessMemory`, `CreateRemoteThread` you'll have to write your own wrapper for, `_WinAPI_WaitForSingleObject`, `_WinAPI_ReadProcessMemory`, `_MemVirtualFreeEx`.

Even once you've done that, you won't be able to just send the image list over to the new application, you can get the handle to the icons, and then write the data to a block of memory, and then pass pointers back.

Do some searching around the forum now you know what you are looking for. There are examples, like [this one](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/141387-createprocessex-run-and-inject-a-dll/) and [this one](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/107360-writing-into-process-using-injection/), search the forum for `CreateRemoteThread` and you'll get a few threads worth reading.

Good luck. If I were you I'd find some way to make your own version of the image list rather than trying to copy theirs.

Comment: +1, This is a very informative post. I appreciate the comment. I will not accept it as the answer so as to not discourage other answers. I myself am a hobbyist programmer and have some experience with these things. I did make a work around actually, but I would still like to find a way to perform this task as I've described above. If nothing else, it contributes to the community. I was wondering though, why do you say I cannot access the data? I have made programs before which read the memory of another process to alter something (i.e. game trainers for cheating).

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd, of course you can access the data, in fact I go on to say how so that was very badly worded of me. What I meant to say was you cannot use another applications handle.

Comment: Oh I see. What I find hard to understand though is that some controls I can manipulate through AutoIt. For example, I have been able to hide the toolbar buttons (by changing the button states) in MS Journal from an outside AutoIt program. I believe you, that I cannot use the handle for that imageList, it is just confusing as to where to draw the line; Some handles I can manipulate and some I cannot. Also, I've noticed you're making a language for combining programming with algebra. That is a very good idea. I made a math parser from LUA once and it was quite challenging.

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd, As far as I'm aware, you can send messages to external window handles. That's about as far as you can go without some trickery.